tpm_crb MSFT0101 :00 : cant request region for resources
While booting try or install Ubuntu I get this error tpm_crb and TOCBLOCK error
This is the error message:
[0.449679] tpm_crb MSFT0101 :00: cant request region for resources [mem 0xe7bb6000-0xe7bb9fff]
[2.812853] ldm_parse_tocblock(): Cannot find TOCBLOCK, database may be corrupt.
[2.812919] ldm_parse_tocblock(): Cannot find TOCBLOCK, database may be corrupt.
I tried disabling fast boot still not working (My bios is legacy)
After I boot my usb
It shows grub menu with options like

Try and install ubuntu
And some options

After I selected try and install Ubuntu option it show the error like
While booting try or install Ubuntu I get this error tpm_crb and TOCBLOCK error
After that the ubuntu installer started and I proceed with all steps.
But when I get to the option "how do you want to install ubuntu" but it doesn't show "boot alongside window boot manager" but I need this option for dual boot.
I think this error occur due to incorrect disk partitioning.
I tried booting ubuntu with unallocated disk space as well as allocated as disk space but either way I show this error.
Everything is fine like booting ubuntu and installer, I think solving this error is the only problem I have.
